# Regular Expression for tokenizing the list of Key=Value pair seperated by comma(,), where Value itself may contain a comma(,) in it

Tags: c#, regex

I have a requirement where I need to tokenise the list of key=value pairs separated by comma.
 Ex: `$val1=abc, $val2=cde, $val3=efg`

Expected Output: 6 tokens

1. $val1
2. abc
3. $val2
4. cde
5. $val3
6. efg

I am using the regex `([^\" =,]*(\"[^\"]*\")[^\" =,]*)|[^\" =,]+` which solves the above problem. But it is not handling the case when the **value** of key=**value** pair has a comma in it.

Ex: `$val1=abc,AB, $val2=cde, $val3=efg`

Expected Output: 6 tokens

1. $val1
2. **abc,AB**
3. $val2
4. cde
5. $val3
6. efg

But with the above regex am getting the output as shown below:
 Output: 7 tokens

1. $val1
2. **abc**
3. **AB**
4. $val2
5. cde
6. $val3
7. efg

Can someone provide a proper regular expression which fits for the above case.

Answer (score 1):

```
[^= ]+(?! \$)
```

[See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/dD9pI6/2)

Reads *any amount of characters, that are not `=` or space and are not followed by a space and `$`*.

Comment: Thanks for response. But it fails for the below case where there is no space between the two entries. Ex: **$val2=app1,lp, $val3=hello,$val4=myval**